# Matching Specific Characters

Tags: regex, excel, match, worksheet-function, countif

Currently we have a spreadsheet like so:

[image: SO29292209 question example]

In the current fields, we want to say:

> IF in that week we have done a Home Visit AND a School Visit
>   Then for the Home Visit Total it should have: `1` and for SV: `1`.

However, when the text is entered with a delimiter: `SV,HV` and I try to apply  a SUMIFS or COUNTIFS it will fail as it does an exact character match and SV!= SV,HV hence it returns 0.

Is there anyway I can make it so that it will return Home Visit as `1` even if there are multiple values like `HV,SV,SV` in the cell?

Comment: Please add more information: what exact formula and in which cells are you using? If you enter "SV" or "HV" or "SV,HV" under "S/Hols Wk 2" column, where do you expect "1" to appear?

Comment: Hi Stribizhev,

So what would happen is that under the School Holidays Field I might put:
HV,SV,SV

Below this I have a separate series of rows for Home Visits, School Visits etc. which will then sum up the instances of HV & SV occuring.
So the 1 would appear in those rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guessing that you may want to sum by row, say in ColumnE for `HV` and `SV` in ColumnF (such labels entered in Row1 for convenience) then maybe something like:

```
=COUNTIF($A3:$C3,"*"&E$1&"*")
```

copied across and down to suit, with cell references adjusted to suit.

Comment: Hi Pnuts,

Thanks for the suggestion. I've just got one other issue;
If i use the wildcard operator to match this - then if I have a string such as:
"HV,SV,WV,HV,HV"
Where there are 3 instances of HV.
If I use this formula:
=COUNTIF(F24,"*"&$S$4&"*")
It will only count the one instance of HV instead of 3.
Is there anyway to solve this?

Comment: Actually don't worry about this - I solved the problem by counting the string using LEN and then using SUBSTITUTE with the phrase I'm looking for then dividing it by this. 

It's all good :)
Thanks for your help though!

Comment: Mmm.
The next problem I'll have to work out is how to sum this all together
for multiple rows as it may get quite messy.
I'll try work it out and let you know if I have any issues. but thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Hi Pnuts,

I've managed to finish the spreadsheet now.
I used LEN & SUBSTITUTE to solve the issue I was having and then referenced this on another "shadow" sheet.

Thanks for the help you offered!